# How to give absolute "file-path" in a java class of a web application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

On local machine (localhost), in a java class file of a web application, I am giving file path as under.

```
  JRBeanCollectionDataSource bean = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(al);
  try {
    print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("D://vivek's//powerSpace//report//bus.jasper",
                                         new HashMap(), bean);
  } catch (JRException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return al;
}
```

But when this web application is hosted on server, how to give the absolute path of the file.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Why do you need an absolute path? Usually there is better ways of doing this. (like creating the file in memory, storing the contents to some temporary file, configuring the root directory of where you store/read files, use the resources folder of your web app, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the resources for this.
EG:
put the bus.jasper into resources folder of your webapp, then use:

```
InputStream resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bus.jasper");
```

and work with the InputStream from there.
If the API of the class you're using is so lame that it needs the filepath use

```
ConstantDataManager.class.getClassLoader().getResource("bus.jasper").getPath();
```

The second solution doesn't work well on Weblogic though.